# How to start using Salesforce DX for internal org customisations

Tags: salesforce

I have read the Salesforce docs and gone through the trailhead units but still can't figure out where to get started with Salesforce DX. I am not a marketplace app developer, I do customisations for clients by creating custom objects, apex triggers etc.

Do i start by tidying up all my existing customisations and rolling them into a DX project? If so, what are the steps for doing that e.g. testing/deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get tired with the clunky Developer Console? Do you work alone? Have you ever had "edit wars" where other developer was editing same file and "hilarity" ensued?

You use changesets? If you push a changeset form dev to uat, testers love it but would like to slightly modify the reports layouts and whatnot (and after a weeek they don't remember what they changed) and they ask you to push UAT version to prod - means you need to recreate the changeset in uat, right? Click click click argh.

If you need to mass change field labels - wouldn't it be nice to run a mass search-replace on your disk and deploy that rather than hunt them object by object and click click click. If you need to change "legalese" in email template footer in 100 emails - isn't that time consuming (and the online editor can mess the markup, even if you don't make mistakes of copy-pasting to MS Word)

A local, offline project acts as backup (even better if you want to use version control), simple way to retrieve & deploy stuff without changesets. There are tons of SFDX commands to load data, reset passwords. There are ways to run code formatters, unit tests. Tools like Winmerge to help you compare sandboxes (without $ for tooling like Gearset)

You can't write Lightning Web Components from Developer Console.

You don't have to jump the whole distance to (un)managed packages. Just use it as local copy of the project.

As for actual steps...

Have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/development-models/ ? "Create project with manifest" is better for sandboxes if you don't think you're ready for scratch orgs etc yet.

This plugin helps with selecting what to download, saves you time hand-crafting the xml: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator. (although there's way to [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm](enable "source tracking" in sandboxes too)).

Which trailheads did you do? If you've been using changesets till now - have you seen https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model/develop-and-test-changes-locally2 ?

If your customers use unmanaged packages this might be good start: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unlocked-packages-for-customers/build-your-first-unlocked-package?trail_id=sfdx_get_started

You can shamelessly <strike>steal</strike> get inspired by https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes. Project has nice sample structure, code formatting tools and lots of [Actions](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/actions) if you want to invest time in automatic CI runs, validating deployments... You can't take it verbatim because it creates "2nd generation packages" and you need a convert to metadata api for production deployment but still - nice example and kept up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your response but wasn't exactly what i was asking about. I understand the benefits of Salesforce DX but was more wondering how I take what I have already done with developer console etc... and turn it into a version controlled project. Do I create a new DX project and retrieve source from production e.g. ApexClasses, CustomObjects etc.. and then commit that to my source control?